# Query for Yes/No box in MS Access 2013

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have a query where I set the criteria to True or Yes for a Yes/No box field.  However, out of the three records with checked boxes from my table, the query results only gives me one record result.  Why isn't the query picking up the other two checked boxes?

Comment: Please edit your post to include the actual table design, the table data and your SQL.

Comment: 4/29 - I just figured the problem today.  In my two tables, I should have had a corresponding record in each table.  It only returned one record in the result because I didn't have a corresponding record in the 2nd table.  Thank you though for taking the time to read my post.